# How can I set timeout grid or store at Ext.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, timeout, ext.net

I will show 375 record in ext.net page but ext.net grid or store default timeout 30 second I need to 130 second but I cant set timeout. my ext.net version is 2.4. How can I set? I try this way but doesnt work.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(everything, 120000);
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById('WorkOrderLinesGrid').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('WorkOrderInvoiceStore').style.display = 'none';
        }, 1200000);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

in asp.net mvc razor syntax,like this

```
    Html.X().Store().ID("store1")
        .PageSize(20)
        .DataSource(Model)
        .Model
        (
            Html.X().Model()
            .Fields
            (
                new ModelField("company", ModelFieldType.String),
                new ModelField("price", ModelFieldType.Float)
            )
        )
        .ServerProxy
        (
            Html.X().AjaxProxy()
            .Url(Url.Action("GetDataFromSQL"))
            .Timeout(120000)
        )
```

Also,You can look that [Extend timeout for loading a store](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?11807-CLOSED-Extend-timeout-for-loading-a-store&p=48065&viewfull=1#post48065)

```
<ext:Store runat="server">
    ...
    <DirectEventConfig Timeout="120000" />
</ext:Store>
```